# changing the values of height attribute of table cells using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tables say table 1 and table 2.(both having equal number of rows)
For each of the rows in table 1, I wish to set the height of the corresponding cells in table 2 equal to the corresponding cell in table 1. i.e table2-row1-col1 = table1-row1-col1 and similar.

Please help me .

Comment: provide some html code for table1 and table2 ple..

Comment: In some cases, questions speak for themselves. This one seems clear; not sure how some table markup would explain the question any more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.each` to loop through the rows in the first table, and use `.eq()` to select the table-2 row which corresponds to each table-1 row:

```
$('#table1 tr').each(function(i,el) {
    var hgt = $(this).height();
    $('#table2 tr').eq(i).height(hgt);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/sCdRk/

Comment: But how to make the table cells height equal.Making the the 'tr' height equal is not the solution.

Comment: All the cells in a table row must be of equal height.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both tables have the exact same number of rows, the below should work. If they differ you'll need to check the existence of a matching table1 row before setting the height.

```
var $table1 = $("#table1");
var $table2 = $("#table2");

$("TR", $table2).each(function(index) {
    $(this).css("height", $("TR", $table1).eq(index).css("height"));
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3YaPj/1/) to prove it works.

Comment: Nice. For a giggle I wanted to make sure it would accomodate multi-line and it held up. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3YaPj/3/

Answer (score 0):

First, you must make sure the two tables have the same number of rows or add some index check codes to avoid OutOfIndex error.

Here is some codes, just FYI:

```
var tbl2Rows = $("#tbl2 > tbody > tr");
$("#tbl1 > tbody > tr").each(function(index){
    console.log($(this).height());
    $(tbl2Rows.get(index)).height($(this).height());
});
```